# How can i write expression in Django 3+?

Tags: django

It is an old version, how to rewrite it to new requirements?

`url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',`

Comment: would `re_path` be a solution here? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#re-path

Comment: You can define a wildcard also like this `reset/<int:uidb64>-<string:token>/`
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#path